# Routing swap In ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing

I have A controller like that

```
public class OldController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int ID, int Year)
    {
       return View();
    }
}
```

And it use a route Like

```
/Old/Index?ID=1000376&Year=566641393
```

I create a modified controller like

```
public class NewController : Controller
{
     public ActionResult Index(int ID, int Year)
     {
         return View();
     }
}
```

Now I need that new controller to use the route

```
/Old/Index?ID=1000376&Year=566641393
```

And old controller use and other route

Comment: You need to update your RouteConfig.cs file to use the new controller. Can you provide a sample of your current config?

Comment: I use only the Default Route @ShaiAharoni

Answer (score 0):

Add a manual route config like

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
    "MyAwesomeRouteName", "/Old/Index",
    new {controller = "New", action = "Index"}
);
```

The routing configuration most likely resides in `RouteConfig.cs`, unless you changed it

Comment: And the old one

Comment: @hemavic I can't understand what you mean, could you please rephrase?